# DKIM Signature fails when header 'h' tag unfold to 2 lines

Tags: dkim

I am writing an email DKIM signature verifier program in java. My problem is a special case:

1 – I don't have any issue in creating body hash. My problem is in signing canonicalized header.

2 – I use a gmail account to created test emails and I verify their header signature properly in many cases. But only some special scenarios fail. I do many tests and recognized when 'h' tag in ' DKIM-Signature' header has 2 lines, signature verification fails.

This is an example of failing header:

```
...
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed;
        d=gmail.com; s=20161025;
        h=mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date:message-id:subject:to
         :cc;
...
```

For clarification I guess my problem is here :

```
        h=mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date:message-id:subject:to
         :cc;
```

Every time 'h' tag unfolded to 2 lines verification fails. I am familiar with line unfolding rules and I can correctly verify signature of headers that unfolded in other positions.

After header canonicalization, the content that should verify signature is:

```
...
dkim-signature:v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=gmail.com; s=20161025; h=mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date:message-id:subject:to:cc; bh=pr1Zv1pbjuW/HrdQ6zZ5mYq51Bi+uidXLGOQ265rvEs=; b=
```

I test many scenarios to modify signing content, hope to correctly verification, include inserting a 'space' in line folding position and signing content become such as :

```
... h=mime-version:references:in-reply-to:from:date:message-id:subject:to :cc; ...
```

I know my question is very specific. But hope someone have experience in DKIM signing and its special cases.

Comment: I am having the same problem, so I am wondering if you were able to solve this and how.

Comment: Had the same problem and here is the reason: dkim header folding must be normalized before computing RSA signature.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the DKIM header you posted is incomplete (bh and b tag missing).

But the second (relaxed) canonicalization of the DKIM header there you added a space in `...:to :cc;...` should be correct. If it still does not verify, take a closer look at the rest of the signed headers too. Maybe there is another error.

---

The unfolding itself does not remove any whitespace besides the CRLF. From https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322#section-2.2.3

> Unfolding is accomplished by simply removing any CRLF
> that is immediately followed by WSP.

So after the unfloding, you are left with `...:to         :cc;...`

In the next step, this is reduced to a single space,
as per https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6376#section-3.4.2

> Convert all sequences of one or more WSP characters to a single SP character.